# How to change button text over time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, time

I have a button on my page. And I would like that button to change language every 2/4 seconds with Javascript. e.g. When the page loads the text of the button will be search, and after 2 or 4 seconds it will change to other languages. It doesn't need to be an infinite loop, just the most simple.

HTML:

```
<button id="search" name="q">search</button>`
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById('search');
//after 2 seconds:
x.innerHTML="Suchen";
//And so on
```

Comment: Use `setInterval()`

Comment: Not sure I like the idea of what you're trying to do here - perhaps instead put a search icon (spyglass) next to the button and try to use the browsers language to set the correct text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('search');
    if (btn.innerHTML == "search")
         btn.innerHTML = "Suchen";
    else
         btn.innerHTML = "search";
   }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most robust and simple solution for your problem. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jay_harris/3838Z/).
Loop through a predefined language dictionary using `setInterval()`

```
var x = document.getElementById('search'),
    // dictionary of all the languages
    lan = ['Search',  'Suchen', 'other'],
    // hold the spot in the dictionary
    i = 1;  

setInterval(function (){
  // change the text using the dictionary
  // i++ go to the next language
  x.innerHTML = lan[i++];
  // start over if i === dictionary length
  i = lan.length === i ? 0 : i;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JtHa5/
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="search" name="q">Search</button>`
```

**Javascript:**

```
setInterval(changeButtonText, 2000);

function changeButtonText()
{
 var btnTxt = document.getElementById('search');
    if (btnTxt.innerHTML == "Search"){
         btnTxt.innerHTML = "Suchen";
    }
    else{
         btnTxt.innerHTML = "Search";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the button to an `input` and use the `value` property instead of the `innerHTML` property.
Here's the Javascript:

```
function changeButton() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
    if (btn.value == "Search")
        btn.value = "Suchen";
    else
        btn.value = "Search";
}
setInterval(changeButton, 2000);
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Search" />
```